# Get status of 'newly-launched' EMR cluster programmatically

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-emr

I'm following [official docs guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/calling-emr-with-java-sdk.html) to write a Scala script for launching EMR cluster using AWS Java SDK. I'm able to identify 3 major steps needed here:

1. Instantiating an EMR Client

   I do this using `AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.defaultClient()`
2. Creating a JobFlowRequest

   I create a `RunJobFlowRequest` object and supply it with `JobFlowInstancesConfig` (both objects are supplied with appropriate parameters depending on the requirement)
3. Running JobFlowRequest

   This is done by calling `emrClient.runJobFlow(runJobFlowRequest)` which returns a `RunJobFlowResult` object

But [RunJobFlowResult](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc//com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/model/RunJobFlowResult.html) object doesn't provide any clue as to whether the cluster was launched successfully or not (with all the given configurations)

---

Now I'm aware that [listClusters()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.html#listClusters--) method of the `emrClient` can be used to get cluster id of the newly-launched cluster through which we can query the state of the cluster using [describeCluster()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/AmazonElasticMapReduceClient.html#describeCluster-com.amazonaws.services.elasticmapreduce.model.DescribeClusterRequest-) call. However since I'm using a Scala script to perform all this stuff, I need the process to be automated (here looking up the cluster id in the result of `getClusters()` will have to be done manually)

Is there any way this could be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have all the pieces there but haven't quite stitched them together.

The cluster's id can be retrieved from RunJobFlowResult.getJobFlowId(). (It is a string starting with "j-".) Then you can pass this jobFlowId to DescribeCluster.

I don't blame you for your confusion though, since it's called "jobFlowId" for some methods (mainly older API methods) and "clusterId" in other methods. They are really the same thing though.

Comment: thank you so much; i'm surprised that the official docs bear no mention of this anomaly that the cluster-id is retrieved as jobflow-id